# Can you increase an app's disk quota using the web UI?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I found [this article](http://blog.troyastle.com/2014/03/setting-disk-quota-for-your-cloud.html) which gives two ways of increasing an app's disk quota: You can change the manifest and deploy or you can run `cf curl`.  But, is there a way to do this from the web UI?

---

I'm going to inline the curl command for posterity:

```
$ cf curl /v2/apps

# Find the metadata.guid for the app you want to increase the disk quota of

$ cf curl /v2/apps/[APP-GUID-HERE] -X PUT -d '{"disk_quota":2048}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cf push [APP-GUID-HERE] -k 2G
```

The dash k option allows you to specify disk quota from the cf cli.

Comment: The question is about the Web UI